# Mockito session set Attribute null pointer exception

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am trying to set the session for testing, but i am getting `NullPointerException`. I have tried a couple of of ways, but could not succeed.

```
class Test {
    public void testOne() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("test", someValue()); //session value is null
    }
}

//This is my Unit Test which have one method giving exception.Why the session  is giving null value....
Class TestUnitTest {

    private TestUnit testUnit;
    private ExternalContext externalContext;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        testUnit = new TestUnit();
        externalContext = Mockito.mock(ExternalContext.class);
        Mockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()).thenReturn(externalContext);
        request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        Mockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
        httpSession = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);
        Mockito.when((request.getSession())).thenReturn(httpSession);
        //I am getting null pointer exception while implementing in this way             

        @Test
        public void testvalueTest() {
            testUnit.testOne(); //Null pointer exception
            verify(httpSession).setAttribute("test", someValue());
        }
        //I am getting Wanted not Invoked while implementing in this way   Wanted not Invoked

        @Test
        public void testvalueTest() {
            verify(httpSession).setAttribute("test", someValue()); //Wanted not invoked
            testUnit.testOne();
        }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong - what is the right approach to set the session?

Comment: I think MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(<T>.class); is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
externalContext = Mockito.mock(ExternalContext.class);
Mockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()).thenReturn(externalContext);
request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
Mockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
```

Mockito works by overriding instance methods, and can't override static methods. Though PowerMock does allow static method mocking, you can usually refactor the calls to static methods into instance methods and then mock using Mockito or other test override techniques.